# Sorting a string by specific values

Tags: r, string, list, sorting

I have the following string:

```
str1<-"{a{c}{b{{e}{d}}}}"
```

In addition, I have a list of integers:

```
str_d <- ( 1, 2, 2, 4, 4)
```

There is one to one relation between the list to the string.
It means:

```
a 1
c 2
b 2
e 4
d 4
```

I would like to sort in alphabetic order only the characters of str1 that have same level.
It means to sort c, b (which have the same value 2) will yield b,c 
and to sort e, d (which have the same value 4) will yield d,e.

The required result will be:

```
str2<-"{a{b}{c{{d}{e}}}}"
```

In addition a,b,c,d and e can be not only characters, but might be words, such as:

```
str1<-"{NSP{ARD}{BOS{{DUD}{COR}}}}"
```

How can I do it with keeping the { in their place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
brkts <- gsub("\\w+", "%s", str1)
strings <- regmatches(str1,gregexpr("[^{}]+",str1))[[1]]
fixed <- ave(strings, str_d, FUN=function(x) sort(x))
do.call(sprintf, as.list(c(brkts, fixed)))
[1] "{a{b}{c{{d}{e}}}}"
```

and

```
[1] "{NSP{ARD}{BOS{{COR}{DUD}}}}"
```

It will work for the first and second case. We first isolate the text with `gsub` and place `%s` instead. That will be used later for `sprintf`. Next we isolate the strings by splitting with `strsplit` on the comma that we placed after each group of bracket symbols. We then sort based on the sorting vector given and save the characters in the vector `fixed`. Lastly, we call `sprintf` on the `brkts` variable that we created at the beginning and the sorted strings.

**Data**

```
str_d <- c(1, 2, 2, 4, 4)
str1<-"{a{c}{b{{e}{d}}}}"
str1<-"{NSP{ARD}{BOS{{DUD}{COR}}}}"
```

Comment: You could alternatively extract the strings with `regmatches(str1,gregexpr("[^{}]+",str1))[[1]]`, might be a bit clearer than the split / subset.

Comment: That is more straightforward. Thank you. I could've also used one of the packages, but I like that this stays with base R.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (using stringr package):

```
words <- str_extract_all(str1, '\\w+')[[1]]
ordered <- words[order(paste(str_d, words))]
formatter <- str_replace_all(str1, '\\w+', '%s')
do.call(sprintf, as.list(c(formatter, ordered)))
```

`words` is an extract of the words between the braces. I ordered those by sorting the combination of the words with `str_d`. E.g. the words will become:

```
1 a 
2 c
2 b 
4 e 
4 d
```

Then I slap it all back together with `sprintf()`.